# Unable to write to flash program memory(PIC18F4620)

Tags: c++, pic18, flash-memory

im trying to write some data into the flash program memory. i read the data sheet and followed the step. And also i edited the linker script for the rom array. below are my codes for flash program memory sequences in C. im trying to write into address 0xFF00.

```
            TBLPTR = 0x3fc000;           // start of erase seq
            EECON1 = 0b10010100;         //EEPGD = 1, FREE = 1, WREN = 1,
            INTCONbits.GIE = 0;
            EECON2 = 0x55;
            EECON2 = 0xAA;
            EECON1bits.WR = 1;           
            INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
            EECON1bits.WREN = 0;    

            TBLPTRU = 0x3F;              // start of write seq
            TBLPTRH = 0xC0;
            TBLPTRL = 0x00;
            for(i = 0; i<64; i++)
            {

                TABLAT = dispData0[i];
                TBLPTRL = i;
            }   
            EECON1 = 0b10000100;         // EEPGD = 1, WREN = 1
            INTCONbits.GIE = 0;
            EECON2 = 0x55;
            EECON2 = 0xAA;
            EECON1bits.WR = 1;
            INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
            EECON1bits.WREN = 0;

            TBLPTR = 0x00ff00;
            dispData3[0] = TABLAT;
            TBLPTR++;
            dispData3[1] = TABLAT;
```

below are the linker script i have edited :

```
    // File: 18f4620_e.lkr
// Sample linker script for the PIC18F4620 processor

LIBPATH .

FILES c018i_e.o
FILES clib_e.lib
FILES p18f4620_e.lib

CODEPAGE   NAME=page       START=0x0               END=0xFEFF
CODEPAGE   NAME=para       START=0xFF00            END=0xFFFF         PROTECTED
CODEPAGE   NAME=idlocs     START=0x200000          END=0x200007       PROTECTED
CODEPAGE   NAME=config     START=0x300000          END=0x30000D       PROTECTED
CODEPAGE   NAME=devid      START=0x3FFFFE          END=0x3FFFFF       PROTECTED
CODEPAGE   NAME=eedata     START=0xF00000          END=0xF003FF       PROTECTED

DATABANK   NAME=gpre       START=0x0            END=0x5F
ACCESSBANK NAME=accessram  START=0x60           END=0x7F
DATABANK   NAME=gpr0       START=0x80           END=0xFF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr1       START=0x100          END=0x1FF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr2       START=0x200          END=0x2FF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr3       START=0x300          END=0x3FF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr4       START=0x400          END=0x4FF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr5       START=0x500          END=0x5FF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr6       START=0x600          END=0x6FF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr7       START=0x700          END=0x7FF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr8       START=0x800          END=0x8FF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr9       START=0x900          END=0x9FF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr10      START=0xA00          END=0xAFF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr11      START=0xB00          END=0xBFF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr12      START=0xC00          END=0xCFF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr13      START=0xD00          END=0xDFF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr14      START=0xE00          END=0xEFF
DATABANK   NAME=gpr15      START=0xF00          END=0xF7F
ACCESSBANK NAME=accesssfr  START=0xF80          END=0xFFF          PROTECTED

SECTION    NAME=CONFIG     ROM=config
SECTION    NAME=DATTBL     ROM=para

STACK SIZE=0x100 RAM=gpr14
```

Comment: is EECON2 volitile? otherwise the compiler could be optimising the writes to it away.

Answer (score 2):

There's two problems with your code. The first is that you're trying to erase and write the flash memory at address `0x3FC000` while trying to read from it at address `0x00FF00`. The second is that read and writing from `TBLLAT` doesn't actually perform the read or write operation.  It's just a staging register, to perform the read or write you need to use the `TBLRD` or `TBLWT` instruction. These instruction aren't available in C, so you need to use inline assembly:

```
 TBLPTR = 0x00FF000      // start of write seq
 for(i = 0; i<64; i++) {
     TABLAT = dispData0[i];
     _asm TBLWTPOSTINC _endasm // write TBLLAT to flash; increment TBLPTR
 }

 ...

 TBLPTR = 0x00FF00;
 _asm TBLRDPOSTINC _endasm //  read flash into TBLLAT; increment TBLPTR
 dispData3[0] = TABLAT;
 _asm TBLRDPOSTINC _endasm
 dispData3[1] = TABLAT;
```

I found about the `TBLWTPOSTINC` inline assembly instruction from this post on the Microchip forums: http://www.microchip.com/forums/m653617.aspx#msg653672

Comment: for some reason it is not reading back the data that i have just written. i used 3fc000 for tblptr because thje data sheet stated that for write, 16bit msb determind the address(?) and the 5 lsb is which 64 memory holding register. for erase, the 5 lsb are ignored. thats why i used 0x3fc000 when im writing to 0xff00.

Comment: I don't under why you would think that means you need to multiply the address by 64. It only means that the lower 5 bits of the address are ignored when erasing. Setting TBLPTR to `0x00FF00`, `0x00FF01`, or `0x00FF3F` and performing an erase operation will erases all 64 bytes in flash memory between `0x00FF00` and `0x00FF3F` inclusive. When writing the lower 5 bits aren't ignored, and a write operation when `TBLPTR` is `0x00FF01` writes to address `0x00FF01` in flash memory.

Comment: i see. thanks for the clarification. anyway the read back isn't correct. Im suspecting it's the configuration bits. i read about section 23 about CPn, WRTn and EBTRn and i disabled all of those. could it be a problem?